# Google script custom function for different column

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

how to adjust my gscript custom function to refer to different column where the columns are separated by other column in the middle. My custom function:

```
function myFunction(values) {
  return values.map((row,i) => { // Loop through rows
    const [item, id] = row;
    if (item.length) {
      const idRows = values.filter(r => id === r[1]); // Filter id
      const itemIndex = [...new Set(idRows.map(r => r[0]))].filter(String).indexOf(item); // Check index of this item in current id
      return itemIndex + 1;
    }
  });
}
```

Then i call it in my sheet by `=myFunction(AD2:AD, AF:AF)`, can see example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFbGsP42fMphedY7wtZ7C3focVDJxxkVXHdf6aC3_D4/edit#gid=1749405914
Column AB (custom function called by `=myFunction(Z2:AA)` ) is when the look up columns are beside to each other, column AG is whats to fix when the look up columns are separated by a column in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If explanations depends on external links, they're subject to be closed. If your request is exactly as the title, Create virtual arrays: `=myFunction({AB:AB,AG:AG})`

Comment: Hi can look into sheet on what i meant about column AB and AG

Comment: I shouldn't have to. If I have to look into your sheet to understand your question, your question is not self contained and is not worthy of being in stackoverflow. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/ Add a table if you want to show your data structure.

Comment: Added in my question. My bad because from my previous question some people asked me to add example link, i thought its more helpful to do that. Now I'll just include both. Thanks

Comment: Did you see the linked duplicate and my previous comment about virtual arrays?  Just send in ``myFunction({AD2:AD, AF2:AF})``

Comment: I would just map the columns that I want from the source into the 2 columns of values with array.map() method.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster sorry i wasnt noticed the curly brackets. Yes that works, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Cooper ok I'll explore, thank you for the suggestion!